# Cannot Instantiate the type Node

Tags: java, installation, nodes

I have 2 classes in my project. One of these classes has the class and contructor for Node:

```
public static class Node {
    public Float key; // sorted by key
    private String val; // associated data
    private Node left; // left and right subtrees
    private Node right;
    private int N; // number of nodes in subtree

    public Node(Float key, String val) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

The other class needs to instantiate a Node. This is how I did that:

```
    Node root = new Node (distArray[0], adArray[0]);
```

I've instantiated other types like that before, and its always worked. Now, however, I'm getting the error from the title of this Question. Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Node is a nested class within the class that its not being instantiated in

Comment: Please include the code in which you tried to create a new `Node` as the context of your call will enable us to answer the question.

Comment: You've made the class static

Comment: Is your Node class a nested class? If not, remove the static keyword from its declaration. If it is, you might have to add the containing class name - `new ContainingClass.Node(...)`.

Comment: I am surprised that your code even compiled at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 2 classes in my project. One of these classes has the class and contructor for Node

If Node is a nested class, as implied by this quote, you should instantiate it with :

```
ContainingClass.Node root = new ContainingClass.Node (distArray[0], adArray[0]);
```

An alternative would be to add an import of your `ContainingClass.Node` class to the class that tries to instantiate it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and yes, the capital P was a typo while posting

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `static` modifier of the class `Node`

```
public class Node{
...
```

Also, note that `public` should be lowercase

Edit: looking back at your wording, it looks like it is a nested static class, so here's what you do to instantiate this

```
OuterClass.Node root = new OuterClass.Node(...);
```

If you don't want to type all of this, just statically import `Node`

```
import static yourPackage.OuterClass.Node;
```

Now your previous code should work fine